# Visual Studio 2010 JScript Editor and large javascript files very slow

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Using a new laptop at work, my Visual Studio 2010 JScript editor basically locks up whenever I open the coffee-script.js v1.2.0 (minimized) file.  It basically consists of a single line that is about 170k characters long.

I have attempted turning off all of my JScript extensions (outlining, etc.) but it hasn't really affected the performance.

Currently my only solution is to **Open With** the **Source Code (Text) Editor** instead of the **Script Editor**.  But as I do a lot of JavaScript at work I'm worried that this may be the harbinger of many other script editor problems on this laptop.  I'd rather not have to work around opening minified files all the time.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Funny, I have the same problem with minified files but nobody seems to care about that. Are we the only ones?

Comment: B.t.w. we are on VS2013 but the problem has not changed